# CTAD doesn't work with defaulted template arguments?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction, ctad, default-template-argument

Compare the following case when I have a class object that takes a vector. The non-deduced parameter T can be substituted fine with the default template argument:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T = int>
struct container
{
    container(std::vector<T> vec) {}
};

int main()
{
    container C = std::vector{1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

This is not the case for my class which is a bit more complicated ([CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:44,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:44,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:44,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:44,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cinitializer_list%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvariant%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Csize_t%3E+struct+obj%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Csize_t+Vs%3E%0Ausing+val+%3D+std::variant%3Cstd::monostate,+int,+struct+obj%3CVs%3E%3E%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Csize_t+Vs+%3D+0%3E%0Astruct+obj%0A%7B%0A++++obj()+%3D+default%3B%0A++++obj(std::initializer_list%3Cval%3CVs%3E%3E+init)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22initializer+of+object+called,+Vs+%3D+%25d%5Cn%22,+Vs)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Csize_t+Vs+%3D+0%3E%0Astruct+container+:+public+obj%3CVs%3E%0A%7B%0A++++container(obj%3C0%3E+init)+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++container%3C5%3E+some_container+%3D+obj%7B1,2,5,2,obj%7B1,2,33%7D,2,2%7D%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:43.35736354273945,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:56.64263645726055,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <variant>

template <size_t> struct obj;

template<size_t Vs>
using val = std::variant<std::monostate, int, struct obj<Vs>>;

template <size_t Vs = 0>
struct obj
{
    obj() = default;
    obj(std::initializer_list<val<Vs>> init) {
        printf("initializer of object called, Vs = %d\n", Vs);
    }
};


template <size_t Vs = 0>
struct container : public obj<Vs>
{
    container(obj<0> init) {}
};


int main()
{
    container<5> some_container = obj{1,2,5,2,obj{1,2,33},2,2};
}
```

This fails with the following error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:29:57: error: class template argument deduction failed:
   29 |     container<5> some_container = obj{1,2,5,2,obj{1,2,33},2,2};
      |                                                         ^
<source>:29:57: error: no matching function for call to 'obj(int, int, int)'
<source>:14:5: note: candidate: 'template<long unsigned int Vs> obj(std::initializer_list<std::variant<std::monostate, int, obj<Vs> > >)-> obj<<anonymous> >'
   14 |     obj(std::initializer_list<val<Vs>> init) {
      |     ^~~
```

But it works when I supplement the template specialization `obj<0>` in the instantiation of the container (in main). Any ideas why this doesn't work for my class and how I can fix it? I don't want to force the user to specify the template each time.

Answer (score 0):

This problem already exists in the simpler case of just

```
auto o = obj{1,2,33};
```

which yields this error:

```
<source>:29:24: error: class template argument deduction failed:
   29 |     auto o = obj{1,2,33};
      |                        ^
<source>:29:24: error: no matching function for call to 'obj(int, int, int)'
<source>:14:5: note: candidate: 'template<long unsigned int Vs> obj(std::initializer_list<std::variant<std::monostate, int, obj<Vs> > >)-> obj<<anonymous> >'
   14 |     obj(std::initializer_list<val<Vs>> init) {
      |     ^~~
<source>:14:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:29:24: note:   mismatched types 'std::initializer_list<std::variant<std::monostate, int, obj<Vs> > >' and 'int'
   29 |     auto o = obj{1,2,33};
```

So, the compiler is unable to deduce, that the three `int`s should be an initializer list. If you add extra braces around them, the compiler recognizes that this should actually be a single list argument instead of three separate ones and it works:

```
auto o = obj{{1,2,33}};
```

This also carries over to the more complicated case:

```
container some_container = obj{{1,2,5,2,obj{{1,2,33}},2,2}};
```

Comment: This only partially answers my question though: Why then does obj<0>{1,2,3} resolve fine? Why does the compiler not thinks that its just three ints in that case?